# Find a basis for a matrix $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W=\lbrace A=(A_{ij}) \in M_{n\times n}(F) \mid A_{ii}=A_{jj} \ \text{for} \ 1 \le i,j \le n \rbrace$
Find a basis for it.

I figure out that matrix looks like
$$\begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & * & *& * & \\ * & A_{11} & * & * \\ * & * & A_{11} & * \\ *&*&*&A_{11} \end{pmatrix}$$

Then the matirx 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & * & *& * & \\ * & 1 & * & * \\ * & * &1 & * \\ *&*&*&1 \end{pmatrix}$$ is a basis for $W$?

Comment: How many matrices are in your basis?  You need to have no more than 16 matrices in your basis (because the vector space of all $4 \times 4$ matrices is 16 dimensional).  As a hint, some of the matrices in the standard basis of $4 \times 4$ matrices are in your space; you'll need to add one additional matrix to those to get a basis, and you're on the right track to finding it.

Comment: Plus that which I wrote above, I add two more basis- upper triangular with 1's(zero diagonal), lower triangular with 1's(zero diagonal). Then I can make $W$ with a linear combination of these three matrices, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The standard basis for $M_n(F)$ is $\{M^{i_0j_0} \mid M_{i_0,j_0} = 1, M_{i,j} = 0 \text{ for $i, j \neq i_0, j_0$}\}$. Of these you certainly need $M^{i,j}$ for $i < j$ or $i > j$, to get the upper and lower triangle. Of the matrices $M^{ii}$ you only need one, the matrix you described in your question. So you exactly have it: you need the basis matrices (of the standard $M_n(F)$) that cover the $*$ entries, but you only need one to cover the diagonal.